# In firefox I am not able to open video tag

Tags: html, video

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
<source src="tutorial.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

this tutorial.mps is stored in the same folder but I am not able to open that video I got that sentence Your browser does not support the video tag.

Comment: Which Firefox version are you running?

Comment: I am using firefox version 11.0

Comment: The answer is what @scessor wrote..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this link about [media format browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements#Browser_compatibility). The firefox doesn't support `mp4` yet. Convert the file e.g. to `ogg` and add an additional `source`-tag.

Comment: I was converted my file to .ogg format and used type as "video/ogg" but still it's not working